# Pandas add columns to transposed periodindex obj?

Tags: python, pandas

New to python and getting up to speed on pandas (0.16.2). I have a df (returned from Quandl) with the observations in rows. I want to transpose the dataframe and then set a 2-column multi-index:

```
>df
Period    Value
2013Q2    10000
2014Q2    15000
2015Q2    12500

>df.T
Period    2013Q2   2014Q2   2015Q2
Value     10000    15000    12500

Desired dataframe after reindex (2-column multi-index):
Period           2013Q2   2014Q2   2015Q2
ID    Measure    10000    15000    12500
```

However, df.columns is a periodindex object after I transpose. I can't add the two new columns I wanted to use to set a multi-index:

```
df['ID'] = 'XYZ'
df['Measure'] = 'EBIT'
DateParseError: unknown string format
```

It makes sense to me that I can't add a non-date column label to a periodindex object. If I instead try to add a column by position, it works, but then I lose the date formatting in my other columns:

```
>df.insert(loc=5, column='ID', value='XYZ, allow_duplicates=False)
>df
Period    173      177      181      ID
Value     10000    15000    12500    XYZ
```

The periodindex was a huge help with my original list - I was able to group by quarter and then filter out the quarters I didn't want. I can probably send this to a dict and then replace the timestamps with labels, but there has to be a better way that I haven't found in the docs yet.

Is there a way I can create two new columns, assign values to my existing observations, and then create a multi-index without losing my column headings? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just build up the `MultiIndex` directly, like this:

```
In [27]: mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('XYZ', 'EDBIT')], 
                                        names=['ID', 'Measure'])

In [28]: df.index = mi

In [29]: df
Out[29]: 
Period       2013Q2  2014Q2  2015Q2
ID  Measure                        
XYZ EDBIT     10000   15000   12500
```